# how to show full screen fragment activity in android?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I know how to show full screen activity but it is not working in fragment activity ?

```
public class Dialog extends Fragment  {
    public Dialog() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to put parent activity as full screen and then the fragment container as Match_Parent then fragment as match_parent.

Comment: would you please clear it on more detail i didn't get it .....I just want show full fragment activity not the mainActivity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `DialogFragment`:

```
public class FullScreenDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you have asked **how to show full-screen fragment activity?**

If you know how to make how to make an activity to full screen. You have to use the same way to make the `FragmentActivity` full screen. Because `FragmentActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`.

```
   ↳    android.app.Activity
               ↳    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Also in your question, The class you have included is `Fragment`, not `FragmnetActivity`.

If you need to make your fragment full screen you have to make your hosting activity fullscreen.

use `getActivity()` method to get hosting activity from the fragment. Then you can make the fragment fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @shmakova worked for me, but then my colleague pointed out a simpler solution. It is enough to have the dialog's style inherit from a style, whose name ends with `NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` and add a `windowNoTitle` element. For example: 
In my Dialog:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AppCompatDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogStyle);
}
```

in `src/main/res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

There are several advantages of such an approach: you don't have to override `onCreateDialog` and can have multiple `styles.xml` instances depending on device features. For example, you can have your dialog extend to full screen only on the smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
public class setWallpaperFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public setWallpaperFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int theme = android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen;
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,theme);
    }
```